# Responsive font sizes - plugin

Tags: tailwind-css

I have one question for u **guyz** (and **gals** ;) )

does anybody know any existing plugin for Tailwind CSS which make font sizes responsive (except for lower and upper screen size where font size is fixed) aka. like that:

```
body { font-size: calc(16px + (26 - 16) * ((100vw - 768px) / (1280 - 768))); }
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { body { font-size: 16px; }}
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) { body { font-size: 26px; }}
```

- **lower screen width** - fixed font size
- **screen sizes in between** - responsive font size from **16px** to **26px**
- **wider screen width** - fixed font size

Comment: Have you tried the Tailwind typography plugin https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin

Comment: If that doesnt help you could define your font-size in VW and VH so theyd always be responsive.

Comment: this topic is useful

Answer (score 15):

1- Define font sizes for each breakpoint on `tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    theme: {
      extend: {
        fontSize: {
          'body-lg': '1rem',
          'body': '.875rem',
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

2- Create classes on `global.css` by importing definitions from config file.

```
@layer base {
  body {
    @apply text-body;
  }

  @screen lg { // applying font size for lg breakpoint
    body {
      @apply text-body-lg;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice, but I want the font-size to be fixed at lower screen size (aka. phones) and also on higher screen sizes (aka. wide monitors) but flexible, not fixed in between (using rem, em, %, vw etc.)...

Comment: You can use calc() functions on tailwind.config.js. Just modify/extend the method above regarding to your needs.

Comment: Put your `fontSize` config inside `extend` object otherwise in-built font-sizes like `text-xs`, `text-md`, etc. won't work. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration

Answer (score 7):

Just put some rule like the following e.g.:

`<project/path/to>/tailwind.css`

```
html {
  font-size: 16px;
  @screen md {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  @screen lg {
    font-size: 26px;
  }
}
```

No need for a plugin.

Comment: Don't you change the base REM on larger screens by putting it on `html`? Shouldn't it better be put on `body`? 

Comment: Yeah you may be right about that, change as thy see fit

Comment: And you can even use @apply there to use tailwind font size classes :) 

I prefer to just set text-sm, text-base.etc. on the body element at each breakpoint. The challenge then is controllign the headers.etc. which should naturally scale up with the font size, something tailwind doesn't support.

Comment: `@apply` is a neat trick, last I used it a couple of years ago, it wasn't well supported by Webpack implementations if I am not mistaken, but it creates an interesting "best of both worlds" CSS coding environment for the frontend developers who want to die on a hill over bespoke CSS, which I kinda agree with in part, e.g. using regular classes for semantic markup, and applying Tailwind classes for styling ) so you don't have mountains of utility classes in your views

Answer (score 2):

Here's my setup for React with [`styled-components`](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) and [`twin.macro`](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro/), it uses hardcoded breakpoints as I couldn't find a way to interpolate breakpoints within `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
// tailwind.config.js

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

const plugin = require("tailwindcss/plugin");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({addUtilities}) {
      addUtilities({
        ".fs-0": {
          fontSize: "2.281rem",
          lineHeight: 1.1,

          "@media (min-width: 768px)": {
            fontSize: "3.583rem",
          },
        },
        ".fs-1": {
          fontSize: "1.802rem",

          "@media (min-width: 768px)": {
            fontSize: "2.488rem",
          },
        },
        ".fs-2": {
          fontSize: "1.424rem",

          "@media (min-width: 768px)": {
            fontSize: "1.728rem",
          },
        },
        ".fs-3": {
          fontSize: "1.266rem",

          "@media (min-width: 768px)": {
            fontSize: "1.44rem",
          },
        },
        ".fs-4": {
          fontSize: "1.125rem",

          "@media (min-width: 768px)": {
            fontSize: "1.2rem",
          },
        },
        ".fs-5": {
          fontSize: "1rem",
        },
      });
    }),
  ],
};
```

```js
// components/GlobalStyles.tsx

import React from "react";

import {createGlobalStyle} from "styled-components";
import tw, {GlobalStyles as BaseStyles} from "twin.macro";

const CustomStyles = createGlobalStyle`
  h1 { ${tw`fs-1`} }
  h2 { ${tw`fs-2`} }
  h3 { ${tw`fs-3`} }
  h4 { ${tw`fs-4`} }
  h5, h6 { ${tw`fs-5`} }
`;

function GlobalStyles() {
  return (
    <>
      <BaseStyles />
      <CustomStyles />
    </>
  );
}

export default GlobalStyles;
```

```js
// pages/_app.tsx

import React from "react";

import GlobalStyles from "components/GlobalStyles";

const MyApp = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyles />
    </>
  );
};

export default MyApp;
```

#### Sources

- [Adding utilities to Tailwind docs](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-utilities)
- [`createGlobalStyles` with `styled-components`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle)
- Typographic scales (default and `md`) generated with [Type Scale](https://type-scale.com/)