# Responsive Tailwind css by Updating Root Font Size (thus rem) Based on @media Query?

Tags: css, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I've been working with tailwind in my Vue project and overall its really good, but its a bit annoying to always write `sm:w-10 lg:w-10 2xl:w-30` (etc) for all of my classes.

So I was thinking, since the width is based on rems, wouldn't it make more sense to just update the root font size (which determines rem value) at the `lg xl 2xl` breakpoints, rather than resetting them on each tag?

I think I could achieve that with something like this on the root component:

```
html { // changed from body to html
    font-size: 16px;


@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  html { 
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
```

But I'm skeptical about doing this as the Tailwind docs don't mention it at all. Can anyone tell me if/why this would be a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to the parent class then everything under applies the same text modifiers.

Eg below increases the size of text as the screen width goes up for all child divs

```
<div class='text-base md:text-lg lg:text-lg xl:text-xl'
  ... All text content inside here will responsively change size
</div>
```

See below links for more info

[Font Size](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-size)

[Responsive Design](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design)

Answer (score 0):

I did this successfully by adding the following to `globals.css`.

```
@tailwind base;


@layer base {
  html {
    font-size: 10px;
    @media screen(lg) {
      font-size: 15px;
    }
    @media screen(2xl) {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late for your problem but after a few searches for the same problem, I think the best approach should be this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72763375/16758013).

For who don't want to travel into another realm with the link: we add some rules to `tailwind.css` file:

```
html {
  font-size: 16px;
  @screen md {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  @screen lg {
    font-size: 26px;
  }
}
```

Tailwind uses `rem` for a reason, and the `font-size` we're modifying here is essentially it.

A few notes is you should be awared that changing the html font-size might lead to some (unexpected? should be expected) behaviors, for example: when we change font-size to 14px, `w-4` will take effect as `w-[14px]` instead of 16px as usual.

Another note is the name of css file you add these code to will depend on where you import tailwind. I emphasize this since I've seen a lot of different pathname being mentioned to the level of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea because changing the root font size affects all properties of tailwind that use `rem` units, not just widths but also padding, margins, font sizes, gaps, etc.. This can lead to big changes across your application with just a single break-point change, making it harder to predict and control the layout's responsiveness.

### Global Impact Example

```
html {
  font-size: 16px; // 1rem = 16px
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  html {
    font-size: 24px; // 1rem = 24px at viewport widths of 1024px and above
  }
}
```

Consider this component intended to have a medium font size, moderate padding, and a bottom margin:

```
<div class="text-base p-4 mb-6">...</div>
```

- **Before the Breakpoint**: Below 1024px,

  - `text-base` might be 16px
  - `p-4` results in 16px padding on all sides
  - `mb-6` gives a bottom margin of 24px (assuming default Tailwind scale mb-6 is 1.5rem)..
- **After the Breakpoint**: Above 1024px, with the root font size increased to 24px,

  - `text-base` could unexpectedly scale to 24px
  - `p-4` would result in 24px padding (instead of 16px)
  - `mb-6` would give a bottom margin of 36px (1.5rem * 24px).

### Consequences

- Components might appear larger or take up more space than intended at wider viewports, leading to unpredictable layout shifts.
- The scaling effect applies to all elements using `rem` units, leading to a lack of control over which elements resize at certain break points and by how much!